# Determinar si un vector incluye en alguno de sus elementos un patrón

Tags: r

Intento saber si hay al menos una coincidencia entre los elementos de un vector y un patrón, utilizo grepl lo que devuelve un vector lógico, pero necesito un sólo valor lógico TRUE si al menos un elemento del vector coincide con el patrón, o FALSE si no hay ninguna coincidencia en ningún elemento con el patrón.

```
periodo <- "año"
grepl(periodo, colnames(data.frame)

# FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Sin embargo, necesito, en este caso, que el resultado sea TRUE.

Gracias,
José Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `any()`:

```
any(grepl(periodo, colnames(data.frame))
```

O bien sumar los `TRUE` por si hay 1 o más:

```
sum(grepl(periodo, colnames(data.frame)) > 0
```